# Пословицы и поговорки

Tags: недопустимая-метка, фразеология

Чем пословица отличается от поговорки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, разница между ними, на первый взгляд, не очень заметна. Однако пословица всегда выражает законченную, часто назидательную, мысль. Поговорка же - это просто присказка, часто без всякого поучительного значения.
Пример пословиц: *"без труда не вытянешь и рыбку из пруда", "работа не волк - в лес не убежит"*.
Пример поговорок: *"яйца курицу не учат", "голод - не тетка", "нашла коса на камень"*.

Answer (score 0):

Как я знаю четкой формулировки в чем отличие нет.

Пишут про назидательный смысл, но это тоже не совсем верно. Пословица в отличие от поговорки содержит логический вывод и, но не все так называемые "пословица" ими являются и не все поговорки - это поговорки. Но так как четкой формулировки что значит "назидательное" нет, то под в категорию пословиц заносят все, что должно считаться назидательным, но вывода там нет, логики нет, значит это никакая не пословица.

Как заметить разницу? Например:

Не все коту масленица - называется поговорка. Странное выражение, ищем, оказывается полное выражение звучит так: Не все коту масленица и Великий пост будет. Теперь понятно почему это пословица, а не поговорка. Далее, на запрос пословицы бьется: "лень - мать всех пороков" - совсем не пословица, но: "лень - мать всех пороков, а отец всех пороков - страх", - уже составляет целостную картину и уже является пословицей. Пословица - это не лозунг вроде "жить - Родине служить", как бы не апатриотично это не звучало. Если бы фраза имела противопоставление вроде "а умирать - Родине честь отдавать", это могло бы быть рассмотрено как пословица. Пословица это то, что обретает смысл или целостную картину в противопоставление (конфликте или согласии фраз). "Один в поле не воин, а путник" - полная пословица, которая обретает не назидательный, но смысл. Один человек не может и не будет стоять за идею, ради себя, ему это не нужно, поле - это бездорожье, что-то где нет четкого понимания о морали, так что одиночка не будет биться за мораль, а будет просто путником, странником, который не несет ни зла ни добра.

То есть пословица - это фраза утверждения чего-то и противопоставление/дополнение ей, рождающие вмести новый смысл или целостный взгляд. Не стоит путать пословицы с лозунгами советского и постсоветского периода. Поговорка часто смысловой обрубец от пословицы или стоп фраза вроде "не делай так" или "ну вот так вот", без возможности вывода.